# Scraping javascript with RCurl

Tags: r, gis

I have been trying and failing to write an R function to scrape and parse geojson data of Uber coverage areas from the company's website.

One can see the visual representation of the polygon I am trying to scrape overlayed on the map displayed here: https://www.uber.com/cities/atlanta Looking in the page source in firefox reveals that the geographic coordinates describing the polygon I'm after are found in this node

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cityJSON = { ... }
</script>
```

So, that is the node I have been trying to grab with a script. However, it seems that that node is not making it into R at all. Running

```
fileURL <- "https://www.uber.com/cities/atlanta"
xData <- getURL(fileURL)
html_parsed <- htmlParse(xData)
print(html_parsed)
```

returns just about everything from the page source except for the node I'm after! Does this have something to do with rCurl not loading the javascript? Am I approaching this problem all wrong?

(tested using OS X Mavericks)

Comment: You and anyone who helps you are in violation of uber's terms of service https://www.uber.com/legal/usa/terms and face potential legal action. Why not sign up for their api?

Comment: Thank you for the warning. You've confirmed by fear about that. I'll abandon this and figure it out with the api!

Answer (score 4):

With httr, stringr and jsonlite packages and the magrittr pipe:

```
x <- GET(url) %>%
  content %>%
  as("character") %>%
  str_extract("(?<=cityJSON = )\\{.*?\\}(?=;)") %>%
  fromJSON
```

Note the resultant list includes a member 'geojson' which will in turn need processing through `fromJSON`.

Comment: Could you open up what is str_extract doing. Works like black magic, is it transforming javascript to json? I really like it, but would like to understand more.

Comment: Note this no longer works on the originally requested page because they've changed the contents (and as others have stated, scraping sites like this may violate T&Cs). For the specific question you now have, I'd suggest you have a look at https://regex101.com/r/2RZODr/1 where I've put up an interactive version of this particular regex using the example posted by the original poster (but adding in the trailing semicolon).

Answer (score 3):

```
library(rvest)
k1<-read_html("https://www.uber.com/cities/atlanta")%>% 
   html_nodes("script")%>%
   .[3]%>%
  html_text(trim=TRUE)
```

you need to use regular expression hereafter to format the data

Comment: The opposite is true. `html` is replaced by `read_html` in the new version. Download new version from github.

Comment: This is perfect. I didn't know about rvest. Though as I commented above I'm going to abandon this approach because of legal issues. Any chance you know where my approach broke?

Comment: @user227710 Could you explain the .[3] ? I'm trying to adapt your code to the 17th script and when I write .[17] it gets everything until that, how is this subset working?

Comment: There is no 17th script. It returns null for me.